# How can i get object from session?

Tags: java, session, playframework-2.0

As the title read, I want to ask how can I get object from session?

I'm trying to upload and save image in an object. After I login, (equal username and password) I set the user in the session,

```
session("user",username);
```

e.g Now, I login with "Admin":

```
session("user",username); // now my session = Admin
```

Then I redirect the user to the upload page. I save this photo like:

```
  MultipartFormData body = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
  FilePart picture = body.getFile("picture");
  if (picture != null) {
        String fileName = picture.getFilename();
        String contentType = picture.getContentType(); 
        File file = picture.getFile();
        Photo photo1 = new Photo();
        photo.name=fileName;
        photo.path=file.getAbsolutePath();
        photo.save();
```

How can I save this picture into Admin ?

I understand that I must have an object to add this photo like :

```
Users user = new Users();
Photo photo = new Photo();
photo.name=fileName;
photo.path=file.getAbsolutePath();
user.photo.add(photo1);   //  I added @ManytoOne in Photo.java
photo.save();
```

Sry if my question is stupid :(

Answer (score 0):

Storing uploaded files in the DB isn't best option as it's usually quite expensive. Instead just save the image on the filesystem and then save the path to it as a common `String` .

Of course you should make sure that has unique filename to avoid overwriting other upload, so check if ie. `myphoto.jpg` doesn't exist and if it is just rename new file to `myphoto_01.jpg`, `myphoto_02.jpg`, etc. You can also add some timestamp to the filename on each upload, so you will not need to check if the filename is unique.

You don't need a separate model for that if for an example you saving an avatar of the user, just add two fields to the `Users` model - `avatarName`, `avatarPath`, both as a `String`.

And finally - if your user can hold unknown number of images separate model as you showed looks like a good option.

#### About session:

As showed in the [documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/JavaSessionFlash) session stores the `String`s - ie.: `session("connected")` contains the e-mail of the '*logged*' user. Of course this is very simple sample and in real world it should be better secured.

In general in session you need to store some unique key of your `User` object, preferably that should not be possible to reverse-engineer or guess that key so it can be for an example some random hash stored with the User object. After reading that hash from the session you can just find the User by this key, et voilà!

Comment: Thanks. i understand what u talking about. But i still want to answer that how can i get object "Admin" from session "Admin" (Session is string ---  right ?)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of what you would like to do.
However I agree with biesior to not store photo in the session.

User class

```
package com.practice;
import java.util.*;

public class User {
    public String name = null;
    public List<Photo> photos = null;

    public User(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    photos = new ArrayList<Photo>();
    }
}
```

Photo class:

```
package com.practice;

public class Photo {
    public Photo() {}
}
```

JSP

```
<%@ page import="com.practice.*" %>
<%
    User admin = new User("admin");
    Photo photo = new Photo();
    admin.photos.add(photo);
    session.setAttribute("admin", admin);
%>
```

Comment: seem your code will create new object. I want update "Admin" object which stored in my database.

Comment: What is the data structure of the "Admin" object? This sample only illustrates how to set an object to session. For your case, you can use getAttribute to get the "Admin" object from the session, set Photo object then put it back.